# Enabling or Disabling EditTExt with CheckBOx not Working

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-checkbox

Not **Disabling** the `EditText` on execution in `onCreate()`. But, when clicking on `CheckBox` the method executes once and then stops execution again.

Anyone help to find the Answer

```
public void EXtraWorkCalc(){
    extraworkCheck = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.workCheck);
   extraworkCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
           if (!compoundButton.isChecked()) {
               extraSpace = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.extraWidthEtxt);
               extraSpace.setEnabled(false);
               extraSpace.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
           } else
               extraSpace.setEnabled(true);
               extraSpace.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing the `EditText` in inside the `checkBox` `setOnCheckedChangeListener`. That's why it's not working.

Initialize your `EditText` (extraSpace) in `oncreate()` or before calling `EXtraWorkCalc()` method.

Move this line to `onCreate()`:

```
extraSpace = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.extraWidthEtxt);
```

Comment: Yor are Right Sir but when i am Initializing it in onCreate() and then Validating like if(TextUtils.isEmpty(extraSpace.getText().toString())){
            extraSpace.setError("Please Enter extra Work");
        } it then If() statement in CheckBox Listner  not Working and Giving me the Error of Number Format Exception